# Checking availability of product

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, modx

I am needing to retrieve product availability through query. The CMS I'm on is MODX.

My database is like this:

**CAMERAS**
mid
model
sku

**RENTALS**
cid
mid (this corresponds to the mid from above)
start_date
end_date

My query is to locate the availability of cameras based on if they are 'rented'.

A user selects his/her start and end date, selects 'locate cameras' and the mysql query looks like this:

```
    $a = $modx->newQuery('Cameras');
    $a->leftJoin('Rentals','Rentals',array('Rentals.mid = Cameras.mid'));
    $a->select(array('Rentals.start_date' <= $start_date(POST data from previous page)));
    $a->select(array('Rentals.end_date' >= $end_date(POST data from previous page)));
    $a->select(array('Cameras.*','Rentals.cid as customerid','Rentals.start_date as start'));
    $availability = $modx->getCollection('Cameras',$a);

    $ret = '<p>There are '. count($availability) . ' cameras available</p>';
```

I added 5 cameras into the database to test, and added one as rented, however the query continues to return 'there are 5 cameras available'. It's not picking up the camera that is 'booked'.

Comment: I am not familiar with modx, but I think your query should have `Rentals.start_date` and `Rentals.end_date` in a `WHERE` clause. Looking at the docs, I think you need http://rtfm.modx.com/display/xPDO20/xPDOQuery.where and http://rtfm.modx.com/display/xPDO20/xPDOQuery.andCondition to do the `WHERE`/`AND`.

Comment: Thanks @Sean this worked. It was my lack of the `where` clause. Those links were extremely helpful...and are now book marked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pick up cameras that have Rentals.startdate >= enddate
Or
Rentals.enddate <= startdate

The choice between <= or < depends on the semantics of startdate (being inclusive or not)

Comment: Thank you for this hint. When combined with the above code from Sean, the code works well.